# BBOX and Projections of WMS services in Geoserver

Tags: raster, geoserver, google-maps, wms, overlay

we have tried to overlay a raster layer on Google map and have some difficulties to align the raster images onto the base map. When it is on the overview (Zoom level 1), it looks like this:

[image: Overview of the raster]

On a lower resolution, you could still spot the mis-alignment in high altitude area such as North Europe and Canada:

[image: Zoom in]

BUT when we zoom into the highest level, the problem has gone:

[image]

We have tried these approaches to address this problem:

1. Change the projection of the raster layer on Geoserver from WGS84 to Web Mercator, does not even shown the image on Google Map.
2. We try to change the bbox option in the request but it returns strange results that we cannot even zoom in.

Do you have any idea why this happen? What can we do to address this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try setting spericalmercator:true in the openlayers map.

Comment: I am calling the wms service directly on Google Map... Use the image layer and overlay it directly on the base map.

Comment: make sure that you request the WMS layer in EPSG:900913

Answer (score 1):

You might try using GeoWebCache, unless your data layer is getting updated often.  GWC ships with GeoServer, and will get you better performance with Google Maps.  It also has a nice shortcut to make things work easier with google maps, see http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/services/gmaps.html  The location of the embedded GWC is '/geoserver/gwc' instead of '/geowebcache'.